# Return entity with sub table collection

Tags: entity-framework

Here is what I have:

```
public class StudentHealthInfoType
{

    public int StudentHealthInfoId { get; set; }
    public bool? HasAllergies { get; set; }
    public List<HealthInfoMedicationType> HealthInfoMedicationType { get; set;}
}

public class HealthInfoMedicationType
{
    public int HealthInfoMedicationId { get; set; }
    public string MedicationName { get; set; }
}

var result = (from u in context.StudentHealthInfos
                  from m in context.HealthInfoMedications
                  where u.RegistrationId == registrationId
                   && u.StudentHealthInfoId == m.StudentHealthInfoId
                   select new StudentHealthInfoType 
                   { StudentHealthInfoId =     u.StudentHealthInfoId,
                      HasAllergies = u.HasAllergies,                                                                    HealthInfoMedicationType = new HealthInfoMedicationType
                     { HealthInfoMedicationId = m.HealthInfoMedicationId,
                       MedicationName = m.MedicationName
                      }                                                                   
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get this error which is show at HealthInfoMedicationType = new HealthInfoMedicationType

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Dis.QueryManager.HealthFormTypes.HealthInfoMedicationType' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

HealthInfoMedicationType needs to be a collection of items returned for one StudentHealthInfoType record. How do I need to setup my objects and then cast them so this query works?

Comment: can you tell me what you want to query ?expected result

Comment: var result = context.StudentHealthInfos.Include(x=>x.HealthInfoMedicationType).FirstOrDefault(f => f.RegistrationId == 1);

Comment: What type is `context.StudentHealthInfos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this if you want to query for a particular registration id and list of HealthInfoMedications you can do like this .

```
var result = context.StudentHealthInfos
         .Include(x=>x.HealthInfoMedicationType).FirstOrDefault(f => f.RegistrationId == 1);
```

//  Result will be StudentHealthInfoType  with list of HealthInfoMedicationType